# Import file types

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to import .stp and .igs files to use as my model for 3D animation.

I simply want to import an image of a tool (in one of the above formats) and rotate it in space.

Comment: No, they need to be converted. And see Import options in the File menu to see all supported formats.

Comment: Many thanks Lukasz. Can you give me any guidance as to the best file type they need to be converted to in order to achieve what I've described?

Comment: If you just want to import and transform an **untextured** model you could try any of them, e.g 3ds. Textures cause problems when importing models and there are many questions about it.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz, that does help...